# CMD Script issue with Delims

Tags: cmd

I have the below cmd script that is not yielding what I would expect:

```
set parent=src\Sandbox
set child=src\Sandbox\SandboxTest
echo %parent%
for /F "tokens=* delims=%parent%\" %%i in ("%child%") do set DIRNAME=%%i
echo %DIRNAME%
```

%DIRNAME% is getting returned as "Test", but I expect DIRNAME to be 'SandboxTest'.

Anyone have any ideas why this is? Is there an issue with my delims?

Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use variable reference syntax.

```
set parent=src\Sandbox
set child=src\Sandbox\SandboxTest
echo %parent%
for /F %%i in ("%child%") do (
    set DIRNAME=%%~ni
    )
```

delims is a array of characters used to split

```
set parent=aeiou
set child=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
for /F "tokens=1-10 delims=%parent%\" %%a in ("%child%") do (
    echo.%%a
    echo.%%b
    echo.%%c
    echo.%%d
    echo.%%e
    )
```

It splits on characters not words.

```
bcd
fgh
jklmn
pqrst
vwxyz
```

type `for /?` for the full range of variable reference syntax.

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

Comment: William, thank you for your input. That's what I was looking for and your solution worked! Much appreciated! -Keith

Answer (score 1):

DELIMS does not define a delimeter phrase - it defines a set of delimiter *characters*. None of the characters in "Test" appear in you DELIMS set, hence the result.

In your particluar cited case, you can get your desired result using:

```
for %%F in ("%child%") do set DIRNAME=%%~nxF
```

Comment: Thanks, dbenham. Your solution works great! It's very clean too.